# HP Ubuntu 11.04 overheat problem, any way to control?

Tags: hp

I bought a new hp i3 laptop and im facing a huge overheat problem on Ubuntu (only cuz it works fine on windows 7).

Any time im working one Ubuntu and running multi programs at same time i get this black screen telling me that laptop will shutdown due to overheat, not to mention burning smell from the side of laptop !

on the other side windows 7 seems to be handling this temp. issue very well and i never had this problem.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any graphics card installed in your laptop??
If yes have you installed the proprietary driver for it?

Open source drivers are not good at handling the cooling of the graphics card. I faced the same issue.

If you have graphics card and have not installed the correct driver then run the following command: **jockey-gtk** and install the driver available for your machine..